# Can I use sups and infs on an increasing function on a closed, bounded interval and state that it is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

In Royden's book, we are given the following proposition:

Let $C$ be a countable subset of the open interval $(a,b)$. Then there is an increasing function $f$ on $(a,b)$ such that it is continuous only at points in $(a,b) \sim C$.

Then, he gives a problem which is similarly stated as

Let $C$ be a countable subset of the nondegenerate closed, bounded invterval $[a,b]$. Show that there is an increasing function on $[a,b]$ that is continuous only at points in $[a,b] \sim C$.

This problem seems very trivial because I could define a function $g(x)$ where $g = f$ on $(a,b)$, and $g(a) = \inf \{ f(x) : x \in (a,b) \}$, if $C$ does not contain the endpoint $a$. The same construction would be used on $b$, but with a supremum. Then what would remain to be shown is that using this definition of $f$ for the endpoints, is continuous on at either endpoint. Is this sort of construction the right idea?

Comment: I'm confused; your definition seems impredicative, i.e., self-referential; aren't you defining $f(x)$ in terms of itself? Or do you mean $inf (x)$: $x$  in $(a,b)$?

Comment: Or, do you mean to define a new function $g(x)$ in terms of the function $f(x)$ that works for $(a,b)$?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to define another function $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$, and use my construction. I will rephrase this.

Comment: I don't see the point of setting g = f when we haven't defined what f is.

Comment: We're not defining $g=f$ ; we're defining a new function $g$ that depends on $f$ ; we want different names for different functions to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question does not mention Royden's construction in the open interval case; that makes it a bit confusing, since whether the construction extends easily to the closed interval case depends on what the open interval construction is.

I don't have a copy of Royden's book, so I don't know what his construction is.  But there is a standard construction here: the case in which $C$ is finite is a very easy one, so suppose $C$ is countably infinite and let $C = \{c_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration.  Then we define

$f(x) = \sum_{n \ \mid \ c_n \leq x} 2^{-n}$.

This function is (weakly) increasing and has a jump discontinuity at each point of $C$.  (If you want a function which is strictly increasing, just add the function $g(x) = x$ to it.)  Moreover, this function has $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow b^-} f(x) = 1$.  So if you extend it $[a,b]$ by taking the value $0$ at $a$ and $1$ at $b$, then **yes**, this construction works to answer your question.

Note also that the extension to $[a,b]$ follows the recipe that you give in your question.  However, for this to work we needed $f$ to be bounded on $(a,b)$.  There are certainly going to be functions which satisfy the property on $(a,b)$ but are not bounded: e.g. add to $f$ a function like the arctangent which has limit $-\infty$ at $a$ and $\infty$ at $b$, and then the extension procedure would not work (unless you allow your functions to take values in $[-\infty,\infty]$, which seems unlikely).

Comment: I will include Royden's construction, but you have the idea for the open interval case.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark I believe there is a minor error: $f$ should be defined with $x\geq c_n$; otherwise it is decreasing.

Comment: @A. Alp Uzman: Agreed and fixed, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Let us start with the open interval (a,b).

(1)  suppose the number of points in C is finite.  Obviously we can make f a function which takes a jump at any point of C, but is continuous otherwise.  Then all the points in S = (a,b) ~ C have a neighborhood in which they are continuous by definition, so it is done.

(2) Next, consider C to be a countable set which is not dense in (a,b). We can use the same f as above, one which jumps at each element of C but is continuous elsewhere.  Then again, all the points in (a,b) ~ C are in open neighborhoods on which f is continuous by definition, so it is continuous at each such point.

(3) The issue is the C which is dense in (a,b). Since C is countable, it can be described as the limit a sequence of finite sets: $R_1 \subset R_2 \subset ...$.  On each $R_n$ we can define $f_n$ as we did in part 1, so that it is continuous on $S_n = (a,b) ~ R_n$ and discontinuous on $S_n$.  Let us only specify in addition that the jump chosen, which we will call q, should be the same for each $R_n$.  We claim the {$f_n$} converge and will call that limit function f.

Why the convergence.  Because each $f_{n+1}$ differs from $f_n$ only at a finite number of points, and contains all the points of discontinuity of $f_n$.

We can hope that this f is our desired function, one which is discontinuous at all elements of C and continuous on S = C ~ (a,b).  Certainly it is continuous at all elements of S, because every $f_n$ is continuous there.  The danger is that it might have become continuous on C as well. However, because the jump at r $\in R_n$ is always q, there is always a sequence of $r_n \in C$ such that $r_n \rightarrow r$ but $f(r_n)$ does not converge to f(r).

Now let us look at the closed interval [a,b].  Since we are constructing f, we can set f(a) to be anything we want, whether a $\in$ C or not.  If we specify f(a), the difficulty is at the point b.  That is, by using a constant jump of q to make f discontinuous on C, we have defined an f which $\rightarrow \infty$ at b.

To deal with this, we are going to have to drop the constant q, and replace it with a sequence {$q_n$} which $\rightarrow 0$ as $r_n$ goes to b. The resulting function f will still be discontinuous at every point of S except possibly b itself.  If b is not in S, then f is okay.

But b could be in S.  I do not have an answer to this.  Perhaps someone else can answer.

Comment: I found this answer to be faulty in places and hard to understand in others.  E.g.: $\bullet$ in (2) the sketched argument seems to want the assumption that $C$ has no accumulation point in $(a,b)$, which is much stronger than the assumption that it is not dense in $(a,b)$.  $\bullet$ By the limit of a sequence of finite sets, you mean *what*: the union?  Are you e.g. adding one point to get from $R_n$ to $R_{n+1}$?

Comment: $\bullet$ How you are building $f_{n+1}$ from $f_n$?  If I start with an increasing function on an open interval and change it at finitely many points so as to get another increasing function, then the second function has the same set of discontinuities as the first.  (I can only modify the function at the points of discontinuity.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Yes, as long as (a,b) is open I think we do not have an accumulation point, and I was proceeding on that basis.   Is this not so?  I wimped out for [a,b] because I couldn't figure out how to handle the potential accumulation point at b.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark All the f's are monotonic and discontinuous at a finite # of points.  If $f_n$ is discontinuous at a finite # of points, $f_{n+1}$ will have all the discontinuities of $f_n$ plus some additional ones. The person who provided a thorough answer said to enumerate the $c_n$, and it would have been clearer if I had thought to say that.  However, I think the $f_n$ should in the limit give the correct f.  If you think not, could you please explain further.  Thank you.

Comment: "Is this not so?" It is not so.  Take for instance the set $\{\frac{1}{2} + 3^{-n} \mid n \geq 1\}$ as a subset of $(0,1)$.  This set has an accumulation point in $(0,1)$ but is not dense.  As for the rest: I do not understand what you've written well enough to easily fix it.  Did you understand my previous comment that you cannot change an increasing function at a finite number of points to get an increasing function with any further discontinuities?  If not, you might want to ask a question about that.  There is only so much room in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I can see there is an accumulation point although the set is not dense.  No I did not understand your comment about changing at a finite # of points.  I presumed that if you introduce more disontinuities, the subsequent points will all be higher to accommodate that.  If I'm way off track here, and you are willing, perhaps we should move this to chat?  I don't know how, but maybe you do.

Comment: I don't participate in the chat function on this site.  "The subsequent points will all be higher to accomodate that."  That means you are changing an infinite number of points.  As for the rest of your construction: truly, I do not understand it.  Since the OP's question has already been answered, if this is a question of increasing your own understanding, please feel free to ask a new question.